# Autorun a bat file after a predefined inactive period

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, bitlocker

Is there a way to auto run the following command after a predefined inactive time?

```
manage-bde -lock G:
```

This command activates the bit lock on windows on a removable G drive.

I want preferably a .bat file on the removable drive that automatically executes and locks the drive after a predefined time of being left unattended.

Say, for example, if the drive is left unattended for 10 min, the command `manage-bde -lock G:` is executed.

Comment: Your title and the first sentence says you want to run a command at a predefined time. Later, you say you want to run a command if the drive is left unattended (what do you mean by 'unattended'?) and not at a predefined time at all. Which is it?

Comment: If you need it run at a specific time, you should look into the Task Scheduler. Please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This might have negative consequence, if you lock a drive with open files.

Your command is almost complete, I would add -ForceDismount.
so `manage-bde -lock G: -ForceDismount

- Add a task in Task Scheduler, select your accountname.
- Check box 'Run with highest privileges'.
- Add a trigger based on Not-Active.
- Edit the conditions (tab) to match your desired not-active period.
- Add action, add batchfile.

In your .bat file add:

```
@ECHO OFF
If exist "G:\Folder" (goto lock) else goto end

:lock
manage-bde -lock G: -ForceDismount
pause
REM Pause, so you read any feedback from the sytem.

:end
exit
```

Replace "Folder" with a folder that exists on the drive.
The if statement will only fire the lock command if the drive is actually unlocked.

Please take note that *inactivity* is measured by keyboard and mouse non-activity. If you are staring at the screen for let's say 30 minutes, this command will also fire. It's like those offices that have motion-detection for their lights. So every 30 minutes the occupant has to wave (or stand-up) to keep the lights on. Like those offices, you are trying to detect absence, based on the absence of motion (or in your case the absence of keyboard and mouse activity) which is simply not the same thing, but a bad approximation. I should write a blog this, it is 2016 and this still happens. Usability nightmare! ;) P.s. The solution is presence detectors! Converting that to your situation: You can approximate this by detecting a USB-key being detached from the system (fires -lock) as it is attached to yourself via a ski-pass retracting cable which pulls the USB drive with you when you leave the room. A-ha. ;)